# ROR link_to parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails

in routes.rb I have such a line

```
resources :ideas
```

and in a view I have:

```
<%= link_to 'My ideas',ideas_path+'?id=my' %>
<%= link_to 'My ideas',ideas_path, :id=>'my' %>
```

first line opens: http://localhost:2000/ideas?id=my
while the second opens: http://localhost:2000/ideas

How to fix the second line?
Bye

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<%= link_to 'My ideas',ideas_path(:id=>'my') %>`

Answer (score 1):

Rails paths sort out your paramaters for you.

To link to a single 'idea' you could do something like ...

```
<%= link_to 'One idea',idea_path(@idea) %>
```

To link to all your 'ideas' then

```
<%= link_to 'All ideas',ideas_path %>
```